# Orbeon Forms: Dynamically Build Dropdown Values

Tags: orbeon

Another basic Orbeon Forms question..

We want to pass a string of data into a form that can then be unpacked and used as drop-down values.

Is this possible, and if so, how would we attempt this?

Many thanks

PeteA

Comment: If you want to pass dynamic data into dropdown you can use simply dynamic dropdown.
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/static-dynamic-dropdown

Comment: Pete, are you thinking of passing this value on the URL (in this case it would be visible and modifiable by end users)? Or are you thinking of passing it on the server, for instance using an HTTP header? Or something else? -Alex

Comment: Hi Pete, have you found a way to populate that dropdown based off a parameter? If not, and this is still on your plate, just let us know, and we'll figure something out. -Alex

Comment: Hi Alex,
 Yes, this question is still open